# What's preventing Boost.Format form using my stream operator overload for optional int?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-format

I want to be able to use a `std::optional<int>` with Boost.Format.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <optional>
#include <boost/format.hpp>

struct SomeType
{
    int x;
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const SomeType& t)  
{
    os << t.x;
    return os;
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const std::optional<int>& t)  
{
    os << t.value_or(0);
    return os;
}

void test()
{
    SomeType t{42};
    std::cout << (boost::format("%s") % t); //this is fine
    std::optional<int> i = 42;
    std::cout << (boost::format("%s") % i); //nope
}
```

The code above gives me the following compiler error:

```
opt/compiler-explorer/libs/boost_1_68_0/boost/format/feed_args.hpp:99:12: error: no match for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::basic_ostream<char>' and 'const std::optional<int>')
    os << x ;
    ~~~^~~~
```

There are no compiler errors if I simply pass `i` directly to `std::cout`.

Comment: Moving it into the boost namespace made no difference, however, moving it to std removed the errors.

Comment: Probably highly relevant if not a duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8111677/what-is-argument-dependent-lookup-aka-adl-or-koenig-lookup

Comment: [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51447860/9593596) is very close, too.

Comment: @Chris_F Moving the overload into namespace `std` might work, but is technically not allowed. I would go with `std::cout << (boost::format("%d") % i.value_or(0));` as the default value is a bit context-dependent anyhow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`boost::format("%s") % i` invokes a call to `operator<<`. Name lookup rule is followed during compiling to find a `operator<<`.

For `boost::format("%s") % t`, both struct `SomeType` and `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const SomeType& t)` is defined in global namespace, by using ADL, `operator<<` is found.

For `(boost::format("%s") % i)`, `std::optional` is defined in namespace `std`, but corresponding `operator<<` is defined in global namespace. By using ADL, boost won't be able to find it. And

> non-ADL lookup examines function declarations with external linkage that are visible from the template definition context,

so the compiler isn't able to find the `operator<<` which you defined.

A workaround: wrap std::optional inside your own ReferenceWrapper, then define the inserter for your wrapper in the same namespace where ReferenceWrapper is defined.